# What's The Best Practices to store large data into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

What's your best practice to store large data into MySQL?

E.g I want to create a site showing second hand car details with following items:

1. List item
2. Car Name
3. Car Model
4. Car Brand Name
5. Car Info 4
6. Car Info 5
7. Car Info 6
8. Car Info 7
9. Car Description........

These are some of the (text) related information which I want to store and it might be more than 30 items.

Now, there are some Images and Videos related to the car, owner information and many other details.

Now, what's the best practice of storing large data into the database?

Comment: That's not really large data. every Database and you didn't tell us which you want to use it works allways the same you insert datat with a insert sql statement. it doen't matter if string or binary data.

Answer (score 0):

First design your database with all data you need.

Because, it depends on your database structure and how you design it.

For images you should store only the link resource, the same for videos.

Answer (score 0):

Define a separate table which only contains the large media and a mediaId as primary key.
In your more business related table you store the mediaId reference to the large media record.
In most business logic or queries you don't want to fetch your large media so keeping them separated will avoid the risk of loading these large objects because you just executed `select * from Car_info`.

```
create table LARGE_MEDIA (
    mediaId as bigint primary key,
    mediaData as BLOB);

create table CAR_INFO (
    carInfoId as bigint primary key,
    mediaID as bigint,
    FOREIGN KEY ...
);
```

If you have really large media you can decide to store them outside your database (file system, content management system) and only store the reference data to your media in your database.